# how to perform math function(mod) in python to only cells with numeric data and skip empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How do I perform mod(%4) to only cells with data and skip empty cells. it can't perform mod to empty cells so I want to skip empty cells.

```
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
A         23   23   10   54   23                               
B         34   12   34   54               
C         98   76
D         11   12   12
E         14   23
```

I tried below code but when a certain column finds empty cell it doesn't perform any action.

```
for i in split.iloc[:,2:]:
   if not np.where(split[i]==''):
       split[i] =split[i].astype(int)
       split[i]=split[i]%4
   else:
       continue

---------------------------------------------------------------

actual output

0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
A         3   3   10   54   23                               
B         2   0   34   54               
C         2   0
D         3   0   12
E         2   3

---------------------------------------------------------------

output expected

0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
A         3   3     2    2    3                               
B         2   0     2    2               
C         2   0
D         3   0     0
E         2   3
```

Comment: I shouldn't add any trailing 0's

Comment: Did you look at the actual result of doing `np.where(split[i]=='')`.  Don't make assumptions - read the docs, and display intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

Assign based on condition:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'1':['',1,2,3,''], '2':[4,7,8,'','']})
   a  b
0     4
1  1  7
2  2  8
3  3
4

df[lambda x: x!=''] = df[lambda x: x!=''] % 4
   a  b
0     0
1  1  3
2  2  0
3  3
4
```